# Why is translate.goog domain using my site content?

Tags: google-translate

This is a my website about nonwovens https://sinta-d.com/

This is a links from an external page from a web server report https://6in7vv7ds4s54txgnqhn3r7ewm-jj2cvlaia66be-sinta-d-com.translate.goog

Why did Google Translate create this page?
How can it be useful for a SEO site?

Comment: Interestingly Google looks like they are trying to disallow crawling using robots.txt, but their robots.txt file is malformed.  https://6in7vv7ds4s54txgnqhn3r7ewm-jj2cvlaia66be-sinta-d-com.translate.goog/robots.txt has a single line `User-agent: * Disallow: /`.  It is missing a new line character after the `*`.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller It looks like the directive works without a carriage return as well. The page is not indexed.

Comment: The suggested answer is this: Google found backlinks from a reputable source for which there is no language version of my website and translated it for users of that country.

Comment: "It looks like the directive works without a carriage return as well. The page is not indexed." - [Google's robots.txt tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) does not recognise the directives when placed on a single line and "allows" crawling. The `...translate.goog` URL you link to includes a `x-robots-tag: none` HTTP response header which will prevent indexing in Google, but not necessarily by other search engines (eg. Bing does not support `none` AFAIK).

Comment: "for which there is no language version of my website and translated it for users of that country." - Although that `translate.goog` page appears to be Ukrainian, which would also seem to be the same as the default language on your site?

Comment: Oddly enough, when you first click on the * translate.goog link, one of the Chrome plugins signaled a redirect to https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=cs&u=https://sinta-d.com/

Comment: However, since the base language at the root of the site is Ukrainian, and Google translates by default from English (in this case, into Czech), the translation page was not formed correctly.